# ASP.NET state service isn’t working in .NET6

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

We’ve used the ASP.NET state service to handle sessions of our two webservers behind a loadbalancer. After changing .net6 it seems that this function isn’t working anymore. What is the solution in .NET6 to handle these sessions properly?

To make it more clear:

We migrated a .NET 4.8 WebProject to .NET 6, we are using for authification with Entity Framwork, MySQL database as database and the webserver is hosted on IIS 10. The login is not saved anymore between the two webservers. Before we used the ASP.NET State Service for exchange the session of login between both webservers. Therefor we added the necessary configs to the WebConfig file, this file is not longer existing in .NET 6 projects.

We allready read the documentation of Microsoft to use MSSQL cache server. We tried to use the MSSQL Server as distributed cache, for manually setting session variables this worked fine, but the login is still not possible with the distributed sql server.

Answer (score 0):

The session cookie, like the authentication cookie uses encryption. The servers need to use the same key. in 4.8 we specified the same key in the web.config (machine key). with .net core, the key is always generated, so we needed to define a common Store for Data Protection Services:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?view=aspnetcore-6.0